# If $\sum _{n=0 } ^{\infty } a _n < \infty$ $\sum_{n =0 } ^{\infty } b _n < \infty$ then $\sum_{n=0 } ^{\infty } a _nb _n < \infty$,

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This seem obvious to be true but I'm unsure how to prove it or if there ara basic results about inifnite sums that apply.

If $\sum _{n=0 } ^{\infty }  a _n < \infty$ $\sum_{n =0 } ^{\infty } b _n < \infty$ then $\sum_{n=0 } ^{\infty } a _nb _n < \infty$, where both $a _n $ and $b _n $ are nonnegative.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another approach is $\sum^\infty_{n=0}a_nb_n\le \sum a_n\sum b_n$.

Comment: Excellent idea. So in fact you can show the stronger statement $\sum \sqrt{a_n b_n} $ convergent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sum_{n}b_{n}<\infty$ implies that $b_{n}<1$ for $n>n_{0}$ where $n_0$ is some positive integer.
Consequently $a_{n}b_{n}\leq a_{n}$ for $n>n_{0}$.